# Can plone.app.multilingual work for partially translated sites?

Tags: plone, multilingual

I'm trying to get plone.app.multilingual to work with a site which is currently in English, but will become partially translated. I'm using plone.app.multilingual rather than the more familiar LinguaPlone because of Dexterity content types used by the site which LinguaPlone does not support.

I have a test site to play with. As soon as I translate one page it seems to create a /en folder for the English content and (e.g.) /fr one for the French. I can switch back and forth between the two language variants of the page, but once I'm in the French language I can't see all the other English pages. As a site visitor this is no use and it ignores the fact that although a browser may be set to prefer French, it might also accept English. I have selected what I believe to be the relevant options to allow fallback to the default site language and it lets me view them if I know the URL of the page, but that's not much use if I don't see that the content is there in the first place.

Can plone.app.multilingual be made to work in such a way that a user can see a page of content in **some** language even if it's not their own, or is my only option to convert the site to use Archetypes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LinguaPlone would handle this case the same way: Make all content 'language neutral', except for where there is a translation.

By marking all your content 'language neutral', it'll be found and displayed to the end-user no matter what language preference has been set. Now, if any of your content *does* have a translsation, you do need to set English as the language for the original version so that it'll only be displayed when English is selected.

To do this, you probably can use a subscriber to the `plone.multilingual.events.IObjectTranslatedEvent`.

As for the creation of `en/` and `fr/` locations for your content, that's the task of the `ITranslationLocator` adapter (from `plone.multilingual.interfaces`, you can override that adapter to provide your own choices. See the [default implementations](https://github.com/plone/plone.multilingual/blob/master/src/plone/multilingual/factory.py) for how this currently works.

Comment: Thank you for this reply. I don't really mind where the content is kept as long as people can see it, however I don't see how it can be that once you are inside /fr/ you would see any content outside - it seems to set the root of the site to that point.

Comment: An example of this - I have "Language Neutral" Events and News which appear to all if I am viewing the site root (which is hard because it wants to redirect me to /en/), however whichever language I then choose I will only see the contents of that language's subdirectory. I don't mind working with this usecase, but at the moment I don't see how it would work for anyone.

Comment: @RichardW: It's set as the navigation root, and search is automatically constrained to that.

Comment: @RichardW: You'd need to override the creation of the language-specific roots, and at the very least not have them be set as navigation roots.